# Integration: Countable Additivity?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

When considering Bochner's theory of integration one notices that having a countable additive measure rather than merely additive measure is not important, or do I miss something?

Comment: My understanding is that integration against a "finitely additive measure" has essentially no convergence theorems, in particular no monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Are you sure about it?

Comment: No; this was only touched on briefly and vaguely in my analysis class. This is why I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: The point is, I guess, that this too is due to the construction only and also not due to countably additive measures...

Comment: I guess I can prove there's no monotone convergence theorem. Suppose $A_k$ are disjoint subsets in the $\sigma$-algebra and $\mu \left ( \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k \right ) \neq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(A_k)$. Then (rather trivially) $\int_{\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k} 1 d \mu \neq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{A_k} 1 d \mu$

Comment: That even proof even applies to other convergence theorems ;)

Comment: @Ian: Can you put your comment as answerso I can accept it as answer? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An integral defined by integration against a finitely additive "measure" lacks the convergence theorems of Lebesgue integration. In particular it lacks the monotone convergence theorem. To see this, pick a disjoint family of sets $\{ A_k \}_{k=1}^\infty$, such that $\mu \left ( \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k \right ) \neq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(A_k)$. Then $f_n \equiv \sum_{k=1}^n \chi_{A_k}$ is a monotone sequence of measurable functions with pointwise limit $f = \chi_{\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k}$, but

$$\int f_n d \mu = \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(A_k) \not \to \int f d \mu = \mu \left ( \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k \right )$$